# pthread_unlock_mutex doesn't wake up waiting thread

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, posix, scheduler

I have two threads, one thread run an loop to check if there is data received by wait on multiple sockets, and another thread try to add an socket to the socket list or remove one.

The code is as following:

**Thread 1:**

```
while (!stop)
{
    // usleep(0)
    AutoLock lock(_socketsLock); // AutoLock will call pthread_lock_mutex/pthread_unlock_mutex.
    Socket* activeSockets = waitOnSockets(_sockets, 50); // Wait 50ms for data on the socket list.
    // Handle the data from socket.
}
```

**Thread 2:**

```
void AddSocket(Socket* socket)
{
     AutoLock lock(_socketsLock);
     _sockets.push_back(socket);
}
```

The problem is `AddSocket` seams cannot got the lock in a long time on `Android` system, I have run the application on Mac, seams the AddSocket wait at most for one loop, but on android it can be 10+seconds.

So I assume the pthread_unlock_mutex doesn't wake up other waiting thread on `Android`. I can add `usleep(0)` in the begin of the loop to resolve this issue, even [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/usleep.html) of `usleep` say `usleep(0)` will be no effect.

But if i add `usleep(0)` there will always thread switch for each loop, which I think will not be good for mobile device performance.

So what's the alternative way to release CPU when call `pthread_unlock_mutex` and doesn't case performance issue, in another word only release CPU when there is thread waiting for the lock?

Comment: Just a thought. Without diving into this, I have the feeling that it smells like a race condition.

Comment: Just because a thread can now take a lock does not mean it will wake up. The thread still has to be scheduled by the OS. I am not sure how many cores your hardware has. But if it only has one why should the current thread go to sleep just to let another thread run? That is why `usleep()` works. It effectively puts this thread to sleep so the OS finds another available thread that can run.

Comment: @LokiAstari, actually the glibc implment will low current thread priority when unlock "return __pthread_tpp_change_priority (oldprio, -1);".

Comment: @ZijingWu: Does not change my original comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

#### Thread 1:

```
while (!stop)
{
    AutoLock addLock(_addLock);
    AutoLock socLock(_socketsLock);

    // Release the addLock here.
    // This gives thread 2 an opportunity to get the first lock while this
    // thread is waiting on the socket.
    AutoRelease addRel(addLock);

    // When this thread finishes it will be forces to sleep if there are
    // any waiting AddSocket requests otherwise it will continue as normal. 
    Socket* activeSockets = waitOnSockets(_sockets, 50);
}
```

#### Thread 2:

```
void AddSocket(Socket* socket)
{
     AutoLock addLock(_addLock);
     AutoLock socLock(_socketsLock);

     _sockets.push_back(socket);
}
```